# Make a domain point to another https domain

Tags: ssl, nginx, dns

I am facing a weird issue. I do not know if it is Nginx related or DNS related but here is the problem :

I have a domain that is fine, let's say `foobar.com` , SSL does not face any issue. Both `www.` and `root` domain work with HTTPS.

I have a second domain, let's say `foobaz.net`, I need to redirect it to `foobar.com` in every situations (both `www.` and `root` domains).

It does actually redirect, but when I try to access `https://foobaz.net/` I get a HTTPS error/warning before being redirected to `https://foobar.com/` after adding it the the SSL exceptions of Chrome (`https://foobar.com/` SSL certificate is OK once I get past `https://foobaz.net/` SSL warning).

I do not know if it is Nginx related or DNS related, any clue of what is happening here ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is your config?

Comment: Have you tried testing both of your servers using SSL labs?

Comment: @ShawnC. I have legacy OVH settings.
I have 2 A records to an OVH IP that resolve to the webmail. (`foobaz.net` and `www.foobaz.net` to this IP).

Then 2 TXT records considered as redirects :
`foobaz.net. => 4|https://foobar.com/`, `www.foobaz.net. => 4|https://www.foobar.com/`

Answer (score 1):

Any https connection checks the ssl certificate before proceeding to do what it needs to do in the server(in your case, a redirection). You may have a certificate for foobar.com, which is perfectly fine, but if you don't have a valid foobaz.com certificate. That's why the error shows up, foobaz is not "secure".

A https connection is secure if all the points between you and the endpoint are secure, not only the endpoint. If foobaz is not certified, that is a non-secure middle point on your connection, and that's why the warning happens.

Get a SSL certificate for foobaz too, and the whole connection will be secure.